# display image from library picture

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I have a library picture called "pictures" on it there is a picture "test" (.png)

I searched how to display this picture inside a webpart, i read that Javascript is perfect for it but i didn't find the pefect way to do it.  I looked on this post ([Display Images from sharepoint library in table](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133985/display-images-from-sharepoint-library-in-table))

At the end i just want to insert the picture on a tag

```
<img src="" />
```

Hope i was clear, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.

- There should be a Image WebPart. All you do is just find the image that you want to use in it and you click OK: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Image-Web-Part-5427941b-10bc-4e5f-8c3f-68637608034d
- You can also use the Content Editor Webpart and just click inside the content, and insert an image there, using Insert -> Image
- You can also just use the Content Editor Webpart and paste in your `img` tag in order to manipulate any parameters. Just click the "Edit Source" at the top.

Comment: i'm doing a site template on visual studio , that's why i need to do something in javascript directly on my default.aspx. So i'm only working on visual studio